# Named arrays with socket.io

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, socket.io

So I am creating a multiplayer game, I use the io.emit command to regularly send updates to the clients with arrays of data.

```
setInterval(function(){  
    io.emit("sendBlocks", blocksClient);      
    io.emit("sendMoreBlocks",test);  
}, 100);
```

blocksClient is a normal array. 
While test is a named array.

```
blocksClient = [{ posX: 0, posY: 0, solid: false },
  { posX: 1, posY: 0, solid: false },
  { posX: 2, posY: 0, solid: false },]

test = [ block1: { posX: 1, posY: 5 }, block2: { posX: 35, posY: 42 } ]
```

The blocksClient variable will work completely fine when arriving to the client.
while the test variable will be a completely empty when it arrives.

Anybody know why and what can be done? Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because there are no "named arrays" in javascript, they are in fact objects with properties, should be as follows:

```
{ block1: { posX: 1, posY: 5 }, block2: { posX: 35, posY: 42 } }
```

Comment: Yeah ok, I understand. But it just seems weird when it works internally on the server. But then when it gets send to the client, no more.

Comment: I'm not sure why i'ts working on the server, but as the tags on your question, seems to me that has something to do with nodejs. If the client are web based, the json response will be invalid unless you send it as an object.

Comment: the OP test variable declaration is not valid syntax. it should throw `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` in both environments. and maybe that is why he is no receiving the value. @Benjadahl Take a look at how are you handling these errors.